# Update query to get new records without a unique key?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of accounting transactions and I am trying to copy them into a new table. I have the copy worked out, but I need to update the copy with any new transactions from my source table. The problem I have is that the source data is coming from a report that links many different sources to create these transactions and doesn't have a unique key.

If I had a unique key, I would create an update query and do a left join from the source table to the copied table and anytime the key is null in the copied table, update those fields.

Since I don't have a unique key, I don't know how to accomplish this. Any ideas?

**-----Edit due to Answers-----**

```
SourceTable
Field1   Field2   Field3

CopiedTable
Field1   Field2   Field3
```

So to update CopiedTable with new records I would do this??

```
UPDATE CopiedTable SET 
       CopiedTable.Field1 = SourceTable.Field1,
       CopiedTable.Field2 = SourceTable.Field2,
       CopiedTable.Field3 = SourceTable.Field3
WHERE (SourceTable.Field1 <> CopiedTable.Field1 AND 
       SourceTable.Field2 <> CopiedTable.Field2 AND 
       SourceTable.Field3 <> CopiedTable.Field3)
```

Comment: Then how are you supposed to know what is the updated value?

Comment: The combination of all of the fields would make it unique is my assumption, I'm not sure of the least amount of fields needed for it to be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to answer the question without seeing the source tables, the destination table and the query.

Use a compound key consisting of all the unique key fields of the different tables.

---

EDIT:

Every table must have a primary key. This is a basic design rule for databases. Let us assume that you have two source tables A and B

```
Table A
-------
A_ID, DataField1, DataField2

Table B (lined to Table A through A_ID)
-------
B_ID, A_ID, DataField3, DataField4
```

Now you can create table C like this

```
SELECT
    CLng(A.A_ID) AS A_ID, CLng(B.B_ID) AS B_ID,
    A.DataField1, A.DataField2, B.DataField3, B.DataField4
INTO
    C
FROM
    A INNER JOIN B ON A.A_ID = B.A_ID;
```

I would make `A_ID` and `B_ID` a primary key in `C`.

If `A_ID` and `B_ID` are AutoNumbers we need to do a trick with `CLng` in order to create regular number fields in C.

If later we want to refill C with fresh data from A and B, we can do

```
DELETE * FROM C;

INSERT INTO C
    (A_ID, B_ID, DataField1, DataField2, DataField3, DataField4)
SELECT
    A.A_ID, B.B_ID, A.DataField1, A.DataField2, B.DataField3, B.DataField4
FROM
    A INNER JOIN B ON A.A_ID = B.A_ID;
```

If we want to update only changed records, we need to link the source with the copy and, in addition, test if we have changes in the WHERE clause

```
UPDATE
    C
    INNER JOIN (SELECT
                  A.A_ID, B.B_ID,
                  A.DataField1, A.DataField2, B.DataField3, B.DataField4
                FROM
                  A INNER JOIN B ON A.A_ID = B.A_ID) AS Src
      ON C.B_ID = Src.B_ID AND C.A_ID = Src.A_ID
SET
    C.DataField1 = Src.DataField1,
    C.DataField2 = Src.DataField2,
    C.DataField3 = Src.DataField3,
    C.DataField4 = Src.DataField4
WHERE
    C.DataField1<>Src.DataField1 OR
    C.DataField2<>Src.DataField2 OR
    C.DataField3<>Src.DataField3 OR
    C.DataField4<>Src.DataField4;
```

The sub-select `Src` could be another stored query.

Comment: `UPDATE table SET value = newValue WHERE key1=12 AND key2=7 AND key3=100`. Just create a WHERE clause, which ANDs all the keys.

Comment: Would <> make it pull in the new records only?